# eval or sed is inserting single-quotes

Tags: bash, shell, sed, sh, eval

I'm trying to automate a command that takes a list of files as arguments and running into an issue where either `sed` or the `$()` evaluation is inserting single-quotes into the returned response.

The total script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
./update $(ls $PWD | sed "s#\(.*\)#$PWD\/\1#g" | sed 's# #\\ #g')
```

Essentially, run `update` where it receives a list of files as arguments. the first `sed` adds the absolute path to the files and the second `sed` replaces spaces with backslash-escaped spaces.

If I run the `ls $PWD | sed "s#\(.*\)#$PWD\/\1#g" | sed -e 's# #\\ #g'` on the command-line, it works as expected but when run inside the `$()` evaluation it wraps every line that received the backslash-escaped replacement with single quotes.

so instead of running:

`update file\ A.txt file\ B.txt fileC.txt`

it runs:

`update 'file\' A.txt 'file\' B.txt fileC.txt`

What can I do to remove those single-quotes?  I've tried piping the output to another `sed` to remove single-quotes but it seems like the matches just put them back.

Comment: It's not adding quotes. But any quotes that are in the output will be processed literally -- quote processing isn't done after expanding variables and `$()`

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is generally not recommended. Why not just `./update "$PWD/"*`?

Comment: If you're using the output of `set -x` to see what it's doing, the quotes are coming from that. If a word contains special characters, it wraps it in quotes so you can see where the word begins and ends.

Comment: Unfortunately the `./update` is out of my control and will only accept a hardcoded list of files and will fail if the wrong filetype is added. $PWD contains many file types.  It also doesn't accept double-quotes paths.

Comment: That's good to know.  Thanks.  I was using `set -x` but the command fails with the same error without `set -x`.  That gives me the impression that `$()` is also wrapping it in quotes.

Comment: It's not wrappping it in quotes. But if the filename contains spaces, it's being split up.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to escape the spaces with the second `sed`. Escapes aren't processed after expanding `$(...)`.

Comment: The shell parses escapes and quotes before expanding `$( )` (or variables, or much else), so having your command add backslashes doesn't do anything useful. You probably need to either just use a wildcard directly (`./update "$PWD"/*`) or put the file list in an array for processing, but I don't understand the constraints well enough to be able to tell you. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and [#20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020), (though I'm not sure they're directly on point).

Comment: Wow.  Thanks Gordon.  `find $PWD -exec ./update {} +` worked with no problems.  It really is all about knowing what tool to use for a given problem.